# Python open() not creating file

Tags: python

This code is not creating a file when called.

```
def editcam(filetext, filename, x, y, z):
    print 'opening file'
    filetext=re.sub(r'location <(\d+),(\d+),(\d+)>', 'location <%d,%d,%d>'% 
(x,y,z), filetext)
    fout=open(filename, 'w')
    print 'file opened'
    fout.write(filetext)
    fout.close()
    return

def main():
    editcam(getfile(),'tmp.pov',0,0,12)
    return
```

Neither of the prints work either. There is no error message. getfile() should return a string. I tried commenting out the re.sub call and replacing getfile() with a hardcoded string. Neither changed anything. Since the prints aren't working, it seems like the method isn't even being called. Any ideas?

Comment: What does `getfile()` do? It sounds like the call to `getfile()` is blocking.

Comment: getfile() retrieves the contents of another file. But like I said, replacing that call with a hardcoded string didn't change anything.

Comment: Is this your full code? If so, you need to manually call the `main` function.

Comment: Oh, that's probably my problem. I remember seeing something that sounds like that, but this is the first time I've ever written python without editing another project. Thanks for the help, sorry for being so new to this. ETA: yeah, that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working with the code below.

```
import re

def editcam(filetext, filename, x, y, z):
    print 'opening file'
    filetext=re.sub(r'location <(\d+),(\d+),(\d+)>', 'location <%d,%d,%d>'%
(x,y,z), filetext)
    fout=open(filename, 'w')
    print 'file opened'
    fout.write(filetext)
    fout.close()
    return

def main():
    editcam(__file__,'tmp.pov',0,0,12)
    return
main()
```